# How do I get the ID of a selected HREF tag in PHP?

Tags: php, href

I have multiple href tags each with a different ID. Now, I want to get the ID of the selected HREF tag I click. How can I do this in PHP?

Thanks

Comment: Assume you mean `<a>` tags.  Please show your code.

Comment: some piece of code would be very helpful to find an answer.

Comment: PHP does not run in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to do that in PHP. You must use JavaScript and pass through GET parameters the ID of the clicked link.

If you have jQuery, It'd be like this:

```
$("a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var a = $(this);
    window.location.href = a.attr('href')+"?clicked_id="+a.attr('id');
 });
```

So in your PHP code, you can use `$_GET['clicked_id']` to identify which one was clicked.

But the simpler way, is to generate unique URL's for each `<a>` tag. So, You can determine which URL was clicked without any JavaScript code, which, in this case, seems to be desnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

### Literal interpretation of the question

You would need to use javascript to complete this as PHP cannot react to mouse clicks as PHP is parsed before it reaches the users browser.

Something like this with jQuery should work.

```
<?php
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">$(\'a\').click(function(){ alert(this.id); });</script>';
?>
```

### With some guess work

To highlight the current page in a navigation menu you could use something like the below.

```
$links = array(
    'Home' => '/home/index.html',
    'About' => '/about/index.html',
);

echo '<ul>';
foreach($links as $name => $url) {
    $class = '';
    if($_GET['ID'] == $name) {
        $class = ' class="selected"';
    }
    echo '<li' . $class . '><a href="' . $url . '">' . $name . '</a>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```